# How to make window started with "START" commandline pause at the end of execution?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a `.bat` file that uses `start` command to run other scripts.

I can make the `.bat` file wait for being closed by me with `pause` command at the end.

But how can I make this pause to the scripts I run?

Main `.bat` is paused but started scripts auto-close themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put inside other scripts' content `pause > nul` to pause them without displaying

> Press any key to continue . . .

on the screen.